# linux 64 bits memory space size?

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel

In Linux 32bit, the kernel occupies 1gb of memory while the userspace will occupy the remaining gigs (~3) - how does this differ to the 64bit kernels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 64-bit x86-64 the split is half to half - i.e. if first bit of address is 0 it's userspace if it is 1 it's kernel space.

In theory it's 8 Exbibytes each (1024*1024 TiB). However only [48-bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses) are implemented in processors now - the first 16 bits must either be all 1 or all 0 (this makes implementation cheaper as TLB and other components can save space). This gives 'merly' 128 TiB for userspace and 256 TiB for kernelspace. However the extension to full 64-bit kernel space with split 8/8 EiB is perfectly possible in future in backward compatible way.

Comment: @user2485710: You don't understand the _question_ or you don't understand the _answer_?

Comment: the question. _2 more to go..._

Answer (score 1):

If [this post](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2012-November/006468.html) is correct, its a 1:1 split - 128TiB for each of kernel space and userspace.

Comment: Thanks DigitalTrauma!